# Could JBoss Seam redirect user's "Last Visited Page" after the use logged in login page?

Tags: java, jsf, seam

**Note**

I have `ServletFilter` which is used to check whether user already logged or not by using `<url-pattern>`. If the user not logged, the redirect to `login.xhtml`.

**My Problem**

After the user logged, my program is always redirect the `dashboard.xml`(based on the `navigation-rule`). I would like redirect `last visited page` automatically. Could you provide the possible way for that?

**Currently My Soluction is work for that**

But, I am not happy to use it. Does `Seam` support? Could you provide the better way?

In my `ServletFilter`, I keep last visited page as below

AuthenticationFilter.java

```
httpSession.setAttribute(Constants.ORIGINAL_VIEW_KEY, requestPath);
```

In my `LoginBean`, to redirect the last visited page after the user logged.

LoginBean.java

```
ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
Application application = facesContext.getApplication();
ExpressionFactory eFactory = application.getExpressionFactory();
ValueExpression binding = eFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{" + Constants.VISIT_KEY_SCOPE + Constants.VISIT_KEY + "}", Visit.class);
binding.setValue(elContext, visit);

ValueExpression originalViewBinding = eFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{" + Constants.ORIGINAL_VIEW_SCOPE + Constants.ORIGINAL_VIEW_KEY + "}", String.class);

String originalViewId = (String) originalViewBinding.getValue(elContext); <--- last visited view id.

UIViewRoot viewRoot = application.getViewHandler().createView(facesContext, originalViewId) ;
facesContext.setViewRoot(viewRoot);
facesContext.renderResponse();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Identity` and `Credentials` is used, the page redirected last visited page(to access the page, the use need to login) automatically after the logged. We have to need configure in `component.xml` as below.

component.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components ----->
   <event type="org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful">
      <action execute="#{redirect.returnToCapturedView}"/>
   </event>
</components>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the following from login.page.xml

```
<navigation from-action="#{identity.login}">
  <rule if="#{identity.loggedIn}">
     <redirect view-id="/view/dashboard.xhtml"/>
  </rule>
```

Comment: my question is last visited page

Comment: you want that the user returns to the page he was the last time he was on the site? Seam doesn't provide that functionality by default, you should add a global page action that stores (on a DB for example) the view-id of the current page, and then upon login, redirect them to that view, check the source code of the **redirect** component for clues on how to redirect